# Set up trigger to get sum of all values in a column

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I am creating a trigger in SQL to sum up all the values in a column after a change is made. I am stuck and encountering an error when I try this:
`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER GET_NUM_ATHLETES 
AFTER DELETE OR UPDATE OF NUM_ATHLETES OR INSERT ON DELEGATION 
BEGIN
  SELECT
    SUM("A1"."NUM_") "SUM(NUM_)"
 INTO x_1 FROM
    "DBF19"."DELEGATION" "A1";
END;
```

`
My table looks like this:

| ID | Num_ |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | 2 |
| XYZ | 4 |

I just used the Oracle SQL Developer GUI to create, but obviously doing something wrong.

Comment: this does not look like mysql

Comment: why do you want a trigger to do a select?  where do you expect to see the results of the select?

Comment: I think `select ... into ...` would generally create a table, but that would fail once the table already exists ... in general this looks like a bad idea as far as a trigger goes, even if it did work.

Comment: @topsail `SELECT ... INTO ...` selects a single row into PL/SQL variable(s); it does not create a table (you need a `CREATE TABLE` statement for that).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a view instead of maintaining the data in a table. That way the view would get the results "live" each time.

And also you wouldn't need to do the extra task of loading data into another table

```
CREATE VIEW NUM_ATHLETES
AS
  SELECT SUM("A1"."NUM_") "SUM(NUM_)"
    FROM "DBF19"."DELEGATION" "A1";
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not create a table, use a `VIEW` (or if you were doing more complicated calculations a `MATERIALIZED VIEW`):

```sql
DROP TABLE num_athletes;
```

then:

```sql
CREATE VIEW num_athletes (id, num) AS
  SELECT id, SUM(num_)
  FROM   DBF19.DELEGATION
  GROUP BY id;
```